# Rails 4 app not asking for user_photos access after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, koala

Rails 4 app has login using facebook. In omniauth.rb am making request for user_photos, as below

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, ENV['FB_APP_ID'], ENV['FB_SECRET_KEY'],
    {:scope => "user_photos"}
end
```

But after logging in, rails app doesn't ask for user_photos access, it only asks permission for public profile.

Any settings to be made at `developer.facebook.com/apps`?

Is it compulsory to submit the app and get it reviewed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading the scope correctly, a quick check from the Facebook provider repo shows the following

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
           :scope => 'user_photos'
end
```

https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#configuring

Notice `scope` is not bounded by `{...}`

Comment: Then you should check with the owner of that repo, sounds like an implementation issue/bug.

Comment: Am able to access my albums and photos. But when I try logging in using friends account, it doesn't ask permission for photos.

Comment: @rAzOr you need to submit that permission for approval to Facebook for public usage if your friend is not a tester/developer of the app https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-user_photos

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit this permission first. By default your application can use only `email`, `public_profile` and `user_friends` permissions.

Go to `your-app` => `Status & Review` => `Items in Review` => `Start new Submission` Then check all permissions, that you need and add them. After facebook reviews your application, it'll be able to use those permissions.